Configuring Azure Pipeline to Pull from Github Hosted Repository using GitHub App
We are currently using an Azure DevOps pipeline to trigger a terraform plan against an existing infrastructure.
Within this pipeline during the terraform init stage, terraform will analyze the scripts and download modules from an external repository. During the initial stage of running this pipeline we encountered the following error.
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

which we resolved by using GitHub PAT inline as following
git config --global url."https://$(GITHUB-USER-ACCT):$(GITHUB-PERSONAL-ACCESS-TOKEN)@github.com".insteadOf https://github.com

However as this adds the additional load of maintaining a PAT, wondering whether we can move from this method to a method of using the GitHub Service connection using GitHub Apps as an authentication mechanism. This Service connection was created using the OAuth application. The Service connection that we used has read permissions on the centralized repository which contains the Terraform modules.
Is there are way to reuse the GitHub Service Connection that has been created using GitHub Apps to clone GitHub repositories from script tasks?
We have tried providing Read Permissions to the GitHub Service Connection to the centralized repository where we have all the Terraform modules. However, that doesn't seem to work as Terraform started to fail when trying to clone the specific GitHub repository from Azure Pipeline.

Yes, You can directly create OAuth service connection in Azure Devops project with your github authorization to access Azure pipelines by logging into your Github account, then create a pipeline which fetches the Terraform module directly from your github repository like below:-
My Azure Devops Github Service connection:-

My Github repository
main.tf root
module "rg_module" {
  source              = "./resource-group"  # Local path to your module directory
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name  # Pass required variables to the module
  location            = var.location
}

Pipeline:-



Azure Devops yaml pipeline code:-
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main  

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true  # Ensure credentials are persisted for fetching code from GitHub

- script: |
    wget -O- https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg
    echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install terraform
  displayName: 'Install Terraform'

- script: |
    terraform init
    terraform plan -var "resource_group_name=my-resrsilicongroup" -var "location=East US" -out=tfplan
  displayName: 'Terraform Init and Plan'

- script: |
    terraform apply tfplan
  displayName: 'Terraform Apply'
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))

Output:-


Thank you for your answer. However, the mentioned approach works only if the Terraform module resides in the same repository. In my case, the source of the Terraform modules are referred to another Private GitHub repository (https://github.com/sid24desai/terraform-modules/blob/main/main.tf#L3).

Try using github provider directly in your providers.tf file - provider "github" {
version      = "~> 4.2"
token        = var.github_token
organization = var.github_organization
}
variable "github_organization" {
description = "The github org you want to manage"
default     = "REDACTED"
}
variable "github_token" {
description = "export TF_VAR_github_token=$MY_TOKEN"
} Reference- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs

If you create the Pipeline from DevOps repo, but the module is from external github repo, I'm afraid it's not supported to use GitHub Service connection using GitHub Apps as an authentication mechanism to download the module.
As per the terraform module doc:
Terraform installs modules from Git repositories by running git clone, and so it will respect any local Git configuration set on your system, including credentials. To access a non-public Git repository, configure Git with suitable credentials for that repository.
It requires credentials from local git configuration, On devops pipeline, we can use persistCredentials: true to keep the credential on the agent(endpioint below is the github service connection):
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: common
    type: github
    name: username/repo1
    endpoint: TerraformTest

steps:
- checkout: self

- checkout: common
  persistCredentials: true         # it's used to keep credential 

- bash: |
    mkdir testfolder
    cd testfolder
    git clone https://github.com/username/repo1.git
    ls

It does store the info:

however, the latter git clone still failed:

Aslo tried for terraform init with same logic, it's failed for same.

Hence, it could be not supported yet.
Edit:
If your repositories are all github ones, it also cannot clone the repo in terraform init.
We need to keep the credential by persistCredentials: true. However, the token kept can be used to push changes to the github repo, but cannot clone the repo. Same for terraform init the module from github.


Thank you for your inputs. I am using the GitHub repositories all the way and no any Azure DevOps Repo. All the pipelines definitions, Terraform modules are maintained under GitHub repository.

@Athiththan, if you create pipeline on github, and add module from another external github repo, checked on my side the result is same, the credential persisted can be used to push changes to the repo, but cannot clone the repo. For terraform init, it will also fail to clone the module.
